# Bootstrap3 HTML set <label> length in a input-group

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I would like to make all the label having the same size as the img below:

[image: labels on the form]

This is the HTML snippet:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ form.area_construida.label }}</label></span>
        <input class="form-control" 
        id="id_{{ form.area_construida.name }}" 
        name="{{ form.area_construida.name }}" 
        value="{{ form.area_construida.value }}"                              
        type="text"/>
    </div>   
</div>   
<br>
<div class="form-inline">   
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ form.area_total.label }}</label></span>
        <input class="form-control" 
        id="id_{{ form.area_total.name }}" 
        name="{{ form.area_total.name }}" 
        value="{{ form.area_total.value }}" 
        type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-inline">   
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><label>Data de Construção</label></span>
        <input class="form-control"  data-validation="date" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd"
        id="id_{{ form.data_construcao.name }}" 
        name="{{ form.data_construcao.name }}" 
        value="{{ form.data_construcao.value }}" 
        type="text"/>
    </div>
    <p>Insira o ano em que o imóvel foi construído</p>
</div>
```

I tried some stuff but no success. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label { width: 70px;}` u can set width to label like this.

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rtdtsy17/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this sufficient?

```css
span.input-group-addon{width:50%}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><label>Area construida</label></span>
        <input class="form-control" 
        id="id_{{ form.area_construida.name }}" 
        name="{{ form.area_construida.name }}" 
        value="222"                              
        type="text"/>
    </div>   
</div>   
<br>
<div class="form-inline">   
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><label>Area total</label></span>
        <input class="form-control" 
        id="id_{{ form.area_total.name }}" 
        name="{{ form.area_total.name }}" 
        value="111" 
        type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-inline">   
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><label>Data de Construção</label></span>
        <input class="form-control"  data-validation="date" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd"
        id="id_{{ form.data_construcao.name }}" 
        name="{{ form.data_construcao.name }}" 
        value="11/12/2011" 
        type="text"/>
    </div>
    <p>Insira o ano em que o imóvel foi construído</p>
</div>
```